# RSS: Symbols not escaped properly

Tags: bug

Questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096583/need-help-to-decompile-a-lua-file) crashing my RSS reader.
The problem are the non-escaped characters:

> LuaQ�����������������������T������Ԁ����@��@A�����A��A��@�N���N�@�@��T������Ԁ��΀B��@A�����A��A��@�N���N@B�@��T������Ԁ����C��@C�����A��A��@�N���N�B�@��T������Ԁ����C���D�����A�

I use RSSOwl.

Comment: Those are NUL characters and they're valid Unicode. How do you suggest escaping them? Looks like a bug in RSSOwl.

Comment: @Stijn @Erik von Asmuth w3 validator said: `XML parsing error: <unknown>:26:348: not well-formed (invalid token)`

Comment: Did you use direct input or point the validator at an URL?

Comment: By the way, Delete Voters, deleting the source question makes debugging this problem quite a bit harder...

Comment: i tried both unfortunately the question was deleted

Comment: Hmmm... I've done a little more reading, and that question contains multiple unicode [shift-out characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_Out_and_Shift_In_characters). Those are valid control characters in XML telling the parser to switch to an alternate character set. I can imagine an RSS reader not liking that if there's just one character set.

Comment: RSSOwl should definitely handle malformed xml better, and SE needs to output valid xml for its feeds.